# Solving the system $y_1'(t)=-y_1(t)y_2(t)\,,\,y_2'(t)=1-y_2^2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following system of ODEs?

\begin{align*}y_1'(t)&=-y_1(t)y_2(t)\\y_2'(t)&=1-y_2^2(t)\end{align*}

My idea was to use the 2nd equation to solve for $y_2$ (Riccati ODE). And then I would plug $y_2$ into the first equation and solve the first equation by separation.

Comment: It seems like you’re strategy should work. Did you have some problem implementing it?

Comment: @Robo300 For the Riccati method I need a solution to start with. So I need to guess a solution for the 2nd ode. Can I simply choose $y_2=1$ because then we have $y_2'=1-y_2^2$? (both sides being equal to $0$). Or which solution should I take instead?

Comment: What makes this problem tractable is that, if you invert the second equation (trading $y_2$ for $t$) then what you have is just $t'(y_2) = (1-y_2)^{-2}$ which can be integrated directly.

Answer (score 1):

The second DE is separable you don't need any particular solution to solve it: 
$$\int \frac {dy_2}{1-y_2^2}=\int dt$$
You can use fraction decomposition:
$$\int \frac {dy_2}{1-y_2^2}=\frac 1 2 \left (\int \frac {dy_2}{y_2+1}-\int \frac {dy_2}{y_2-1} \right )$$
Then solve first DE:
$$\frac {y'_1}{y_1}=-y_2$$
$$(\ln y_1)'=-y_2$$

Comment: Okay so I get $\ln \big((\frac{y_2+1}{y_2-1})^{1/2}\big)=t+c \Rightarrow \frac{y_2+1}{y_2-1}=e^{2t}c \Rightarrow y_2=\frac{e^{2t}c+1}{e^{2t}c-1}$. Do I have to substitute this $y_2$ into the first equation or can I pick $c=1$?

Comment: Good job @user728962 yes you need to substitute that function in the first equation and get $y_1$

Comment: You need to have two constants so keep the constant as it is @user728962